# Angular $scope usage best practice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In one of my views i use an **ng-repeat** directive in order to list my **products** (properties are irrelevant):

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl>  

  <table>  

    <tr ng-repeat="product in products">  

      <td>{{product.name}}</td>  

      <td><input type="button" ng-click="removeProduct(product)"/></td>  

    </tr>  

  </table>  

</div>
```

**MainCtrl is as follows:**

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.products = [...];

    $scope.removeProduct = function(product){

    }   

});
```

My question here has to do with the **removeProduct()** function and the optimal way to implement it.

**From my understanding:**

1. ng-repeat creates a new scope in each repetition (lets call it $local)
2. $local inherits from $scope which in turn inherits from the root scope
3. Inside removeProduct() function **$scope** refers to **$scope** while **this** refers to **$local**
4. Both $scope and $local have access to products inside removeProduct(). $local has access cause inherits products from $scope

Inside removeProduct(), i need a way to find the passed product's index and splice it from the array.

I can implement this in **3 ways**:

1. Using $scope.products
2. Using this.products
3. Using none of the above, and passing products as a second parameter to the function in the view [removeProduct(product, products)]

**Is there really any difference? Should i prefer one way over the other and why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between options 1 and 2 there's a difference that using `this` you'll access `products` via the current scope's prototype i.e. `$local.$parent` or `$local.__proto__` (`$local` is the new scope created by `ng-repeat` like you suggested). You won't notice performance impact from the fact that you access `products` using the prototype (even if the prototype chain lookup takes `O(n)`). Anyway, I guess that passing `products` as parameter will have greatest performance but the difference is negligible.

In my opinion the best option is the first one in your list. At least it makes the code more readable because you explicitly initialise the property `products` of `$scope`, so in `removeProduct` it'll be clear where `products` can be found. For understanding the second one you must know that the current scope of the `removeProduct` function is new one and it's parent scope is the outer `$scope` which keeps reference to the `products`...If someone new to Angular reads this it'll be less clear for him.